# socket.io join clients from two rooms

Tags: javascript, node.js, chat, socket.io

I want to join clients from two rooms into a new room. Is there a way to achieve this? Like:

```
io.sockets.clients(room1 , room2).join(room 3);
```

Comment: Little experience in socket.io, not sure what the rooms are. What are the rooms (typeof room1)? What library are you using?

Comment: I assume by rooms you mean namespaces... Actually I think it's not as easy as you write up there. You have to send a message to both rooms to connect to a newly created room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var rooms = ['room1', 'room2', room3]; // list of rooms

socket.join('room1'); // assign the room on connection

var clients = io.sockets.clients(rooms[0]); // list of all clients in room1

for (client in clients)
    {
        clients[client].leave(rooms[0]); // leave room1
        clients[client].join(rooms[2]); // join room3
    }
```

Repeat the same for room2. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**For people using socket.IO versions 1.0 or greater this may not work.** Try the following code for the same.

```
var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms['Current Room Name'];

for (var clientId in clients ) {

     //this is the socket of each client in the room.
     var clientSocket = io.sockets.connected[clientId];

     //If you want, you can remove the client form the first(current) room
     //clientSocket.leave('current room');

     clientSocket.join('new room to join');   

}
```